# Como executar um metodo dentro de uma textBox apenas se o usuario dar enter?

Tags: c#

Estou tentado executar um método dentro de uma textBox , apenas se o usuario dar enter.
Verifique que tenho que usar o Keypress, porem nao estou conseguindo aplicar. Quero que quando o usuario coloque o codigo do produto dentro da textbox e de enter, ele consiga visualizar o produto.
Codigo Abaixo :

```
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        try
        {
            int Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);

            ProdutoDAL d = new ProdutoDAL();

            Produto p = d.ConsultarProduto(Codigo);

            if (p != null)
            {
                txtDescricao.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_descricao);
                txtReferencia.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_referencia);
                txtComplemento.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_descricao2);
                txtCodBarras.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_codbarras);
                txtCustoMedio.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_customedio);
                txtValorAVista.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_avista);
                txtValorTabela.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_tabela);
                txtValorPromocao.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_promocao);
                txtValorComDesconto.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_desconto);
                txtLinha.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_linha);
                txtSetor.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_setor);
                txtfigura.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_figura);
                txtMarca.Text = Convert.ToString(p.Estoque_marca);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PRODUTO NAO CADASTRADO");

            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("ERRO AO CONSULTAR PRODUTO" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: C# não é minha praia mas sabendo que é usado pra web vale perguntar: essa textbox é HTML? Se for vc tem que capturar o keypress com JavaScript (jQuery usando algo como keyup ou change). Se for web avisa que eu dou um help no lado do JS. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Se tiver mesmo de ser só quando for utilizada a tecla `Enter` pode utilizar o seguinte:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // Seu codigo aqui
    }
}
```

Aqui, o evento [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) vai ser disparado assim que o utilizador carregar `Enter` (o evento [`KeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) espera que o utilizador carregue e solte a tecla).

Se por outro lado for sempre que o utilizador complete a acção de preencher a `textbox`:

```
private void textBox1_Validated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Aqui, o evento [`Validated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) vai ser disparado quando o conteúdo da `textbox` for validado.

Normalmente não existe nenhuma validação por defeito, mas caso queira adicionar a sua própria lógica (ver se o código do produto esta correcto por exemplo) pode fazê-lo com recurso ao evento [`Validating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (ocorre quando o controlo perde o *focus* mas antes de sair do controlo em si).